# Printing elements of a tuple

Tags: c++, cout, stdtuple

I am trying to print the elements of a tuple returned by a function where I am comparing the elements of a vector of addresses to those in a database. The fields are: 32-bit int representing the address, int for prefix matching, string containing ASN, string containing matching address, string containing the original address being queried.

```
for (auto itr = IPs.begin(); itr != IPs.end(); itr++) {
    tuple<int,int,string,string,string> entry = Compare(*itr, database);
    string out = get<3>(entry) + "/" + to_string(get<1>(entry)) + " " + get<2>(entry) + " " + get<4>(entry) + "\n";
    cout << out;
}
```

I want each line of the output to look like this:
"{prefix}/{# bits of prefix} {ASN} {address}\n"
However, the output looks like this:

```
12.105.69.1528 15314
12.125.142.190 6402
57.0.208.2450 6085
208.148.84.30 4293
208.148.84.16 4293
208.152.160.797 5003
192.65.205.2509 5400
194.191.154.806 2686
199.14.71.79 1239
199.14.70.79 1239
```

The expected output is:

```
12.105.69.144/28 15314 12.105.69.152
12.125.142.16/30 6402 12.125.142.19
57.0.208.244/30 6085 57.0.208.245
208.148.84.0/30 4293 208.148.84.3
208.148.84.0/24 4293 208.148.84.16
208.152.160.64/27 5003 208.152.160.79
192.65.205.248/29 5400 192.65.205.250
194.191.154.64/26 2686 194.191.154.80
199.14.71.0/24 1239 199.14.71.79
199.14.70.0/24 1239 199.14.70.79
```

The part that confuses me the most is the fact that when I print each element on separate lines by replacing each separator with line breaks, it prints the elements correctly:

```
12.105.69.144
28
15314
12.105.69.152
12.125.142.16
30
6402
12.125.142.19
57.0.208.244
30
6085
57.0.208.245
208.148.84.0
30
4293
208.148.84.3
208.148.84.0
24
4293
208.148.84.16
208.152.160.64
27
5003
208.152.160.79
192.65.205.248
29
5400
192.65.205.250
194.191.154.64
26
2686
194.191.154.80
199.14.71.0
24
1239
199.14.71.79
199.14.70.0
24
1239
199.14.70.79
```

I suppose that I could just write another function that formats the line breaks into the correct format afterwards, but I am curious about what is causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you print it directly to `cout` without all those temporary strings?

Comment: Sorry, that was just me trying random things after cout << gave the same thing.

Comment: Maybe string from `entry` contain some garbage?

Comment: I feel that is not the case on account of when I print everything separated by line breaks. I changed every string literal to line breaks and the elements output correctly. Out of ideas on what is happening.

Comment: But have you checked that by inspecting string content directly?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is there some way to inspect the string other than printing it?

Comment: You can use debugger to inspect string buffer memory.

Comment: can you provide a very short program that generates a dummy tuple and attempts to print it? (Do both one-line and multi-line, if they are giving different answers.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a little more code, so it can be debugged to precisely track the problem?

I think `tuple` and `get` are used correctly.

I guess the problem is in the content of strings or at least in the string returned by `get<2>(entry).

Here is a little example which shows what might be wrong

```
std::string aa = "AAAAA\r"; //"\r" is extra character in aa string
std::string bb = "bbb";
std::cout << aa + " " + bb; //output is " bbbA" not "AAAAA bbb"
```

The problem obviously doesn't occur when each strings is printed separately in each line.

Double check if string returned by `get<X>` doesn't contain any special characters or contain OSX end of line mixed with Linux or Windows end of line